# How i change the student number if the user insert "Y" and How can I display the two inputted values if the answer is "N" straight away?

Tags: c#

My first problem is how can I change the number in the "INSERT STUDENT {0}" after the two Inserted value. As you can see my code  display "INSERT STUDENT 3" and it will always display like that. The condition is if I always enter "Y" everytime the code ask me it will always the Student number untill I inserted "N". And my second problem is that the code that I made is it always display the "INSERT STUDENT 3" even I enter "N".

here's my code

```cs
List<string> studentName = new List<string>();

string insertStudentOne = "INSERT STUDENT 1:";
string insertStudentTwo = "INSERT STUDENT 2:";
string listOfStudent = "List of Student:";

string studentOne;
string studentTwo;

Console.Write(insertStudentOne);
studentOne = Console.ReadLine();
studentName.Add(studentOne);

Console.Write(insertStudentTwo);
studentTwo = Console.ReadLine();
studentName.Add(studentTwo);

string answerStr;
do
{
    string selectAnswer = "DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: ";
    Console.Write(selectAnswer);
    answerStr = Console.ReadLine();
    // get the user input
    int addedStudent = 2;
    int sum;
    sum = addedStudent + 1;
    Console.Write("INSERT STUDENT {0}: ", sum);
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    studentName.Add(name);
    // add the new user to a list or an array
    // then repeat the steps until the user gives an input other then "Y".
} while (answerStr == "Y") ;


Console.WriteLine(listOfStudent);
foreach (string nameStnt in studentName)              
    Console.WriteLine(nameStnt);

Console.ReadKey();
```

The code that i made is run like this if you try it in your IDE.

```
Program output #1
INSERT STUDENT 1:BRYAN
INSERT STUDENT 2:JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: Y
INSERT STUDENT 3: FRANK
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: N
INSERT STUDENT 3: JOYCE
List of Student:
BRYAN
JOHN
FRANK
JOYCE
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Program output #2
INSERT STUDENT 1:BRYAN
INSERT STUDENT 2:JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: N
INSERT STUDENT 3: JAMES
List of Student:
BRYAN
JOHN
JAMES
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Program output #3
INSERT STUDENT 1:BRYAN
INSERT STUDENT 2:JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: Y
INSERT STUDENT 3: FRANK
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: Y
INSERT STUDENT 3: JOYCE
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: N
INSERT STUDENT 3: JAMES
List of Student:
BRYAN
JOHN
FRANK
JOYCE
JAMES
```

As you notice in my code in program output #2 even i insert "N" it will ask me if i want to continue adding student instead of displaying  two first value and it add one student supposedly not bacause it will display the two first value. And the Student number always print like this
"INSERT STUDENT 3:" The program should add 1 number if the answer is "Y" in "INSERT STUDENT" the program should print "INSERT STUDENT 4" "INSERT STUDENT 5" "INSERT STUDENT 6" until i insert the letter "N" in condition if i want to continue

The desired or expected program should be like this:

```
Program output #1
INSERT STUDENT 1:BRYAN
INSERT STUDENT 2:JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: Y
INSERT STUDENT 3: FRANK
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: N
List of Student:
BRYAN
JOHN
FRANK
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Program output #2
INSERT STUDENT 1:BRYAN
INSERT STUDENT 2:JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: N
List of Student:
BRYAN
JOHN
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Program output #3
INSERT STUDENT 1:BRYAN
INSERT STUDENT 2:JOHN
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: Y
INSERT STUDENT 3: FRANK
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: Y
INSERT STUDENT 4: JOYCE
DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ADDING STUDENT (Y/N)?: N
List of Student:
BRYAN
JOHN
FRANK
JOYCE
```

The program should print like this. As you see there's alot of difference in what program i make.

Answer (score 1):

For what I've got from the question you have 2 problems but then you listed the same one 2 times, either way the error with the "Insert student N" that returns always 3 is because you instanciated the variable and set it to 2 inside the cycle, so it resets every time and then 2 + 1 = 3 every time, what you should do is create the variable outside the cycle so it doesn't get overwritten every time (we are speaking about that
`int addedStudent = 2`
Let me know if you had some more problems about this so that we can try to resolve!